# How can I get multiple xml nodes in Nant using xmlpeek?

Tags: .net, nant

I want to get all the node's value those are name after "name". But it seems like Nant xmlpeek can only get one node from xml. Is there any other way to get all the nodes those name after "name"?

## xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<QAEnvironment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <user>
                <name value="clientA" />
        <name value="clientB" />
        <name value="clientC" />
        <name value="clientD" />
    </user>
</QAEnvironment>
```

==============================================================================

## nant script :

```
<xmlpeek
    file="A.xml"
    xpath="/x:QAEnvironment/x:user/x:name/@value"
    property="clientName"
    nodeindex="3">
     <namespaces>
        <namespace prefix="x" uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />
    </namespaces> 
    <echo message="clientName: ${clientName}" />
</xmlpeek>
```

===============================================================================
Result - clientName: clientD (as nodindex = "3")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `<xmlpeek>` task wasn't designed to return multiple results, as far as I can tell. According to its official description:

> If the XPath expression specifies multiple nodes the node index is
>   used to determine which of the nodes' text is returned.

If you have a reliable way of determining the number of same-named nodes, you can try to run a `<foreach>` loop on those. Otherwise, I suppose the only alternative you have is creating a custom NAnt task for this. The nant.contrib project doesn't have anything for this purpose, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion is a recursive "loop":

```
<target name="get.xml.nodes">
    <property name="counter" value="1" if="${not property::exists(counter)}" />
    <property name="counter" value="${counter + 1}" if="${property::exists(counter)}" />

    <property name="temp" value="${node}" if="${property::exists(node)}"/>

    <xmlpeek file="file.xml" nodeindex="${counter}" xpath="/node" property="node" failonerror="false" />

    <call target="get.xml.nodes" unless="${node == temp}" />
<target>
```

Like Yan said, I don't think you can technically do this and `<foreach>` doesn't actually support this. [LoopItems](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/enums/NAnt.Core.Tasks.LoopTask.LoopItem.html) can only be Files, Folders, Lines, or Strings.

Comment: So after much pain and after upvoting, discovered the above solution will not work with nAnt .85 and greater.   Ability to recurse was removed in .85 RC and never reinstated.   See http://sourceforge.net/p/nant/bugs/275/

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @sirdank is the most elegant but does not work for nAnt versions .85 and greater.   Given that, here's a simple mix of Nant and embedded VB.net that will accomplish the same:

```
<target name="parseNodes">


   <script language="VB">
     <references> 
<include name="System.dll" /> 
<include name="System.Xml.dll" /> 
     </references> 
     <imports> 
       <import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" /> 
       <import namespace="System.Xml" /> 
       <import namespace="System.Xml.XPath" /> 
     </imports> 
     <code><![CDATA[

public shared sub ScriptMain(thisProject as Project)
    Dim xmlDoc as new XmlDocument()
    Dim nodes as XmlNodeList
    Dim packageString as string

    xmlDoc.Load(thisProject.properties("path"))

    nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("myNode")

    for each node as XmlNode in nodes
        nodeString += package.Attributes.itemOf("someAttribute").value & ","    
    next

    thisProject.properties("nodes") = nodeString

 end sub

     ]]>
     </code>
   </script>


   <echo message="Nodes: ${nodes}" />       

<foreach item="String" in="${nodes}" delim="," property="node">
        <echo message="${node}" />
</foreach>


 </target>
```

Note that if you have a large file you should probably go with XPath in the VB code.